# RabbitMQ admin APIs for posting a message to a queue

Tags: soapui

I am using the api : **/api/exchanges/vhost/name/publish** to publish a message to a queue via SOAPUI. The pay load is a 200 line json. It is successful sometimes but with the response time of around 23 seconds which is not acceptable. But getting a connection reset error sometimes too.  Did somebody experience the same behavior? Appreciate any solutions.

Thanks
Bimal